# Construct object in another class after initializing variables

Tags: c++, class

I have something like the following:

QuadMesh.h:

```
#include "StructureIpsim.h"  // this is a struct

class QuadMesh {

public:
QuadMesh(StructureIpsim s) {//do stuff}

};
```

SEMPotential.h:

```
#include "QuadMesh.h"
#include "SpecialFuncs.h"

class SEMPotential {

public:
StructureIpsim SI;
QuadMesh mesh;
SEMPotential( //args);

};

SEMPotential::SEMPotential( //args) {
// init structure in here, need to call functions from SpecialFuncs.h to do so
// How to construct the QuadMesh object mesh?  Can't put in initialization list.
}
```

As you can see, the `QuadMesh` object takes in a `StructureIpsim` sruct, but this struct must be initialized using several functions in the constructor of `SEMPotential` before being passed to the `QuadMesh` constructor.  What's the standard way around this?

Comment: A good design would be for `StructureIpsim` to be correctly set up by its constructor (whose arguments you supply from `SEMPotential`'s constructor via the constructor initialization list)

Comment: If this is not possible, you can cause `mesh`'s construction to be delayed by using `std::shared_ptr<QuadMesh>` instead, which you don't assign until you are ready.

Comment: Another option would be for `QuadMesh` to have a default constructor that does nothing, and a function you call to set it up when you are ready

Comment: @MattMcNabb: If replacing a directly-contained member, don't you thinkg `unique_ptr` would be better than `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Does that work properly when the default copy-constructor or copy-assignment occurs?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: No, it breaks the compile.  Which I would say is better than *silently doing the wrong thing*, which is what you will get from `shared_ptr`.  To automatically do the right thing, probably `boost::optional` would be wanted.

Comment: Clever, it wouldn't have occurred to me to use `boost::optional` for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *CAN* use the initializer-list.  Use a helper function, which should probably be a private static member function, that accepts the relevant arguments, does the calculations, and returns a `QuadMesh` object.  Use the initialization list to initialize the member from the return value of that helper.

```
class SEMPotential
{
    static QuadMesh mesh_creator( /* args */ );
public:
    QuadMesh mesh;
    SEMPotential(/* args */) : mesh(mesh_creator(args)) {}
};

QuadMesh SEMPotential::mesh_creator( /*args*/ )
{
    StructureIpsum s;
    // init structure in here, calling functions from SpecialFuncs.h to do so
    return QuadMesh(s);
}
```

As Matt McNabb points out in his comment, that helper function *could* be a constructor of `StructureIpsum`.  But I present a solution that doesn't require modifying `StructureIpsum` or `QuadMesh` class definitions.

If you want to preserve the `StructureIpsum` instance, use the helper method trick to initialize it, and then simply use it to initialize the mesh:

```
SEMPotential(/* args */) : SI(ipsum_creator(args)), mesh(SI) {}
```

Initialization order of members is guaranteed (it's the order they appear in the class, the ordering in the initialization list has no effect).

Comment: @bcf: Because the helper function is called before an instance of `SEMPotential` exists (it's still being created).

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: This is also really good way of initializing a const member that is a dynamic container type, e.g. std::vector that you want to populate based on a constructor argument or some other runtime parameters.